# VBA Send Message to another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have one workbook running continuously and updating every xx minutes. There are 10 other workbooks that reference this workbook and are open as well. When WB1 gets an update for one of the other workbooks say WB6 then I want to either refresh WB6 or have a message pop up telling the user to refresh. I want the message from WB1 to only go to the relevant other workbook.

Not sure if this is possible and I have no idea where to start.

Thanks for any help
Tom

Comment: Are these workbooks all open and running on the same computer? Then you don't need to "send" a message you can just popup a message saying "please refresh WB6" or run the update automatically from WB1. I don't understand what exactly the issue is here. I think you need to be more specific.

Comment: No they are on the same network and are using the .xlam addin

Comment: Different people have the workbooks open at the same time. Right now I have to verbally tell the other user to click the vba refresh button to update. Setting a timer is not an option for auto updates.

Comment: I cannot imagine any possibility without a timer. Why is a timer no option for you? This would be exactly the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will re-explore the timer option.